# How do I get the inner text of a xml tag when there is already content in it?

Tags: php, xml, arrays

Here is the example xml I am using :

```
<contact id="43956">
 <personal>
      <name>
           <first>J</first>
           <middle>J</middle>
           <last>J</last>
           Some text...
      </name>
      <title>Manager</title>
      <employer>National</employer>
      <dob>1971-12-22</dob>
 </personal>
</contact>
```

I got the `Some text...` but now i need my code to read the entire xml document. It also isn't reading the values inside the xml... as you can tell I have never used `XMLReader` before.

This is what I get:

`Array ( [contact] => Array ( [id] => 43956 [value] => some sample value ) [first] => [middle] => [last] => [#text] => Some text... [name] => [title] => [employer] => [dob] => [personal] => )`

Here is the code I have now:

```
function xml2array($file, array $result = array()) {
$lastElementNodeType = '';
$xml = new XMLReader();
if(!$xml->open($file)) {
    die("Failed to open input file");
}
while($xml->read()) {
    switch ($xml->nodeType) {
        case $xml::END_ELEMENT:
            $lastElementNodeType = $xml->nodeType;
        case $xml::TEXT:
            $tag = $xml->name;
            if($lastElementNodeType == 15) {
                $result[$tag] = $xml->readString();                 
            }
        case $xml::ELEMENT:
            $lastElementNodeType = $xml->nodeType;
            $tag = $xml->name;
            if($xml->hasAttributes) {
                while($xml->moveToNextAttribute()) {
                    $result[$tag][$xml->name] = $xml->value;
                }
            }
    }
}
print_r($result);
}
```

I thought about making this function recursive, but when I tried that it made the array really messy.

I had a version of this, but it still didn't output the `J` in the `first`, etc. :

```
function xml2assoc($xml) { 
$tree = null; 
while($xml->read()) 
    switch ($xml->nodeType) { 
        case XMLReader::END_ELEMENT: return $tree; 
        case XMLReader::ELEMENT: 
            $node = array('tag' => $xml->name, 'value' => $xml->isEmptyElement ? '' : xml2assoc($xml)); 
            if($xml->hasAttributes) 
                while($xml->moveToNextAttribute()) 
                    $node['attributes'][$xml->name] = $xml->value; 
            $tree[] = $node; 
        break; 
        case XMLReader::TEXT: 
        case XMLReader::CDATA: 
            $tree .= $xml->value; 
    } 
return $tree; 
}
```

Comment: You really should be using the built-in [SimpleXML](http://php.net/book.simplexml) class instead of that ... unneeded *abomination* of a copy/paste.  It was built back around the turn of the century, was bad then, and is even worse now.

Comment: @Charles I used this code as well `$array = json_decode(json_encode((array)simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($this->file))),1);'` But it was slower and performance is really important. It also didn't include the text that I needed.

Comment: With all that massive amount of code you've posted in your question, where exactly is the place (in the php code) at which you're not able to extract the text-value you're looking for? And you probably not want to use `SimpleXML` but [`XMLReader`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php) in your case.

Comment: I just edited my question. And I am using `XMLReader` like you suggested. Now my question is how do I grab just the text before I get to the next inner tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Take 1

I think what you're going to need to do is save the type of recent nodes or at least the last one so it's available to test against. In short, at least as you present it in your sample XML, you're going to encounter an `ELEMENT_END` node type, a `TEXT` node type with the text you're looking for, and then another `ELEMENT_END` node type.

So you're going to need a `case $xml::TEXT`, and you're also going to need to save the previous node type so that your parser knows that, under normal circumstances it should either be expecting a new `ELEMENT` event, or an `END_ELEMENT` event, but has instead received TEXT. That'll be the signal you need to capture the text to a temporary variable with `readString()` and either save it for your purposes, or wait to see if the next node is also a `ELEMENT_END` at which point you could save it and clear the temporary variable.

### Take 2

Now that we know a bit more of what you're hoping to end up with (i.e, Since you are looking to capture the whole tree and not just specific information from it), I would suggest you stick with the recursive version of the function. I modified the one you have slightly (see the TEXT and CDATA cases for the main substantive change).

```
function xml2assoc($xml)
{
    $tree = null;
    while($xml->read())
    {
        switch ($xml->nodeType)
        {
            case XMLReader::END_ELEMENT:
                return $tree;
            case XMLReader::ELEMENT: 
                $node = array('tag' => $xml->name, 'value' => $xml->isEmptyElement ? '' : xml2assoc($xml));
                if($xml->hasAttributes)
                    while($xml->moveToNextAttribute()) 
                        $node['attributes'][$xml->name] = $xml->value; 
                $tree[] = $node;
                break;
            case XMLReader::TEXT:
                $tree["text"] = $xml->value;
                break;
            case XMLReader::CDATA:
                $tree["cdata"] = $xml->value;
                break;
        }
    }
    return $tree;
}
```

The output in this case looked like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tag] => contact
            [value] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [tag] => personal
                            [value] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [tag] => name
                                            [value] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [tag] => first
                                                            [value] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [text] => J
                                                                )
                                                        )
                                                    [1] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [tag] => middle
                                                            [value] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [text] => J
                                                                )
                                                        )
                                                    [2] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [tag] => last
                                                            [value] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [text] => J
                                                                )
                                                        )
                                                    [text] => Some text...
                                                )
                                        )
                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [tag] => title
                                            [value] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [text] => Manager
                                                )
                                        )
                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [tag] => employer
                                            [value] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [text] => National
                                                )
                                        )
                                    [3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [tag] => dob
                                            [value] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [text] => 1971-12-22
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
            [attributes] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 43956
                )
        )
)
```

I assume this is what you're going for with minor edits, though we're really just re-inventing the wheel here. I hope the XML you need to parse isn't particularly large.

Comment: Okay I got the text. However my code isn't going through the entire xml doc. I will edit my question so you can see what I have.

Comment: I feel a bit like I'm shooting at a moving target here, but I'll update my answer above to address the changes to your question.

Comment: Sorry bout that. Thanks. It works. Yes I am going to be working with a very large xml file. Will this code cause problems? The xml file I will be using is here:

Comment: the xml file I will be using is here: www.expekt.com/exportServlet?category=SOC%25

Comment: The advantage of a stream-based parser is that you don't have to load the whole XML structure into memory to work with it (and your code still does). They're complicated, it's usually necessary for multi-MB files. Your file is ~600k; you should be fine. You might want to profile the time to load the structure into SimpleXML versus this method to make sure the savings are worth the headache. If the XML changes never or rarely it may be more sane to use SimpleXML to help slowly transfer necessary data to SQLite or another DB once/occasionally on the backend and serve front-end users from the db.

Comment: Okay, That is exactly what I am trying to do. The xml changes from every hour to every day. It depends on the game schedules. I am trying to put the info into an array and then upload it into a MySQL db. Can I just use `simplexml_load_file ` or something to load the xml file? Or are you suggesting changing the method I parse the xml?

Comment: You can, and it will save you a lot of trouble over a stream-based parser for such a small file. I generally try to avoid optimizing until I'm sure it's going to matter (or until a working iteration is done); I would suggest going with the fastest/simplest method to code for now and save the XMLReader version of the code in case you get it working and decide the performance is unacceptable.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate it. I just have some more question. I am trying to open this file www.expekt.com/exportServlet?category=SOC%25 it is a xml file and it is not opening. Is there any particular reason that you can thing of. I am using this code to open it `$xml = new XMLReader();
$xml->open('www.expekt.com/exportServlet?category=SOC%25');
$array = xml2assoc($xml);
print_r($array);
$xml->close();`